# Permission to add new Availability tests in Application Insights without access to resource group

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We have a resource group ourweb-prod-ai that contains our website resources and Application Insights.

I want to add permission for a user to view and change the availability tests in Application Insights without giving permissions to the whole resource group.

I first added Contributor access on the Application Insights resource. Then he could see the Overview view. After that I added Application Insights Component Contributor access on the resource group. Then he could see the details of the tests.

I seems that to be able to add new tests I have to add Contributor access to the whole Resource Group. Is this really so or is there another way so I won't have to expose the other resources in the group?

Comment: If you add `Contributor` role to the Application Insights resource, I think he will be able to add new test. It did not work for you?

Comment: @JoyWang No, it did not work. When he was contributor in Application Insights he could see the tests but neither view their details nor add new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we should assign `Contributor` role to the related resource group. After that, we can add an availability test and view the detail. Azure also supports custom role. When using `Get-AzureRmProviderOperation Microsoft.Insights/*` to know the resource provider operations that are available to define permissions, there's no specified operation.

Comment: As always be aware of the security implications of any such grant at a higher level of access. But this works great for non-prod environments as the devs often have access at that level.